# Tkinter askquestion dialog box

Tags: python, tkinter, tkmessagebox

I have been trying to add an askquestion dialog box to a delete button in Tkinter.  Curently I have a button that deletes the contents of a folder once it is pressed I would like to add a yes/no confirmation question.

```
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox

top = Tkinter.Tk()
def deleteme():
    tkMessageBox.askquestion("Delete", "Are You Sure?", icon='warning')
    if 'yes':
        print "Deleted"
    else:
        print "I'm Not Deleted Yet"
B1 = Tkinter.Button(top, text = "Delete", command = deleteme)
B1.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

Everytime I run this I get the "Deleted" statement even if I press "No".  Can an if statement be added to a tkMessageBox?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem is your `if`-statement. You need to get the result from the dialog (which will be `'yes'` or `'no'`) and compare with that. Note the 2nd and 3rd line in the code below.

```
def deleteme():
    result = tkMessageBox.askquestion("Delete", "Are You Sure?", icon='warning')
    if result == 'yes':
        print "Deleted"
    else:
        print "I'm Not Deleted Yet"
```

Now for as to why your code seems to work: In Python a large number of types can be used in contexts where boolean values are expected. So for instance you can do:

```
arr = [10, 10]
if arr:
    print "arr is non-empty"
else:
    print "arr is empty"
```

The same thing happens for strings, where any non-empty string behaves like `True` and an empty string behaves like `False`. Hence `if 'yes':` always executing.

Comment: It is so clear when you see the answer.  I had tried various combination of 'if == something' but did not think to use the tkMessageBox as the input, I got hung up on trying to use the 'yes' and 'no' of askquestion for the inputs.  Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Running your function `deleteme()` creates a blank tkinter box as well. Any idea what might be causing this?

Answer (score -1):

Below is the code to ask question in messagebox of exit window and then exit if user press Yes.

```
from tkinter import  *
from tkinter import messagebox
root=Tk()
def clicked():
  label1=Label(root,text="This is text")
  label1.pack()
def popup():
  response=messagebox.askquestion("Title of message box ","Exit Programe ?", 
  icon='warning')
  print(response)
   if   response == "yes":
      b2=Button(root,text="click here to exit",command=root.quit)
      b2.pack()
  else:
    b2=Button(root,text="Thank you for selecting no for exit .")
    b2.pack()
button=Button(root,text="Button click",command=clicked)
button2=Button(root,text="Exit Programe ?",command=popup)
button.pack()
button2.pack()
root.mainloop()
```