# "are you sure" exit prompt in python tkinter GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, prompt

I have written my first program on Python 3.4, including a GUI using Tkinter. (Hooray!)
I have an option to save input (create a text file and a csv from what they've input), or people can X out of the program without saving the info.

Is there a way to bring up an "are you sure you want to exit without saving?" prompt when people click the X to exit?

Comment: Already asked, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643007/intercept-tkinter-exit-command

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Didn't find it when I looked, must have been searching wrong terms.

Answer (score 0):

Use tkMessageBox maybe.

Here's an example from another query [Tkinter askquestion dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244753/tkinter-askquestion-dialog-box).

Comment: He was asked how to execute a command when user tries to terminate the program. Not how to show a messagebox.